# Matching any character and or undefined newlines with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, findall, logfile-analysis

I have to parse a log txt file with regex in python. This is an example of a txt (named `file`):

> 20/01/18, 08:11 - Peter: Good morning
>
> How are you?
>
> Peter 20/01/18, 09:00 - Caroline: I am fine thanks. You?
>
> 20/01/18, 09:01 - Peter: Good
>
> I had some problems few days ago.
>
> Now I am happy
>
> Are you working?
>
> 20/01/18, 09:02 - Caroline: No I have to go to the supermarket to buy
>   vegetables
>
> 20/01/18, 09:12 - Peter: Nice!
>
> Where are you now?

I tried to parse the whole text with this regular expression:

```
f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
texts=re.findall('(\d+/\d+/\d+, \d+:\d+\d+) - (.+?): (.*)',f.read())
f.close()

df= pd.DataFrame(texts,columns=['data','name','text'])
```

However, I have problems when matching one or multiple newlines in python (for example the text of Peter at 09:01). I also try to work on https://regex101.com/ to find a possible solution but I didn't succeed.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/qLibiH/1

Comment: BTW, line `Peter 20/01/18, 09:00 - Caroline: I am fine thanks. You?` seems like a typo in input data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the following text until the next date at the beginning of a new line, you could use a negative lookahead matching all lines that don't staart with a date like pattern:

```
(\d+/\d+/\d+, \d+:\d+\d+) - (.+?): (.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+/\d+/\d).*)*)
```

About the last part `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+/\d+/\d).*)*)`

- `(` Capture group 3

  - `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\r?\n`  Match a new line
    - `(?!\d+/\d+/\d).*` Assert what is on the right is not a date like format
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)`Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/khFR2l/1)

Answer (score 0):

By default, `.` will not match a newline. You need to [use DOTALL mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) to make it match newlines:

```
re.findall('(\d+/\d+/\d+, \d+:\d+\d+) - (.+?): (.*)', f.read(), re.DOTALL)
```

It works:

```
>>> import re
>>> s="""
... 20/01/18, 09:01 - Peter: Good
... 
... I had some problems few days ago.
... 
... Now I am happy
... 
... Are you working?"""
>>> re.findall('(\d+/\d+/\d+, \d+:\d+\d+) - (.+?): (.*)', s, re.DOTALL)
[('20/01/18, 09:01', 'Peter', 'Good\n\nI had some problems few days ago.\n\nNow I am happy\n\nAre you working?')]
>>> _
```

This does not solve the problem of matching the entire rest of the text, though!

See @the-fourth-bird's answer for a real solution.

Another. more explicit way to handle it is to read the file line by line, and check if a line is a continuation or not.

```py
rx = re.compile('^(\d+/\d+/\d+, \d+:\d+\d+) - (.+?): (.*)$') # Note the ^.
texts = []
for line in input_file:  # Files iterate line by line.
  new_match = rx.match(line)
  if new_match:
    texts.append(list(new_match.groups()))  # We want a list
  else:
    # We have a continuation line; append it to the last item of group.
    last = texts[-1]
    last[-1] += line  # Update in-place.
```

This may be easier to reason about.

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` does **nothing** to `.`, it only changes the meaning of the `^` and `$` anchors. You mean [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).